# Loading .nii file in xtk in 3D

Tags: xtk

As in the one for DICOM files, would it be possible to have a simple example of displaying a .nii file with XTK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest case would be something like that

http://jsfiddle.net/p683A/1/

```
// create and initialize a 3D renderer
var r = new X.renderer3D();
r.init();

// create a X.volume
var volume = new X.volume();
// .. and attach the single-file dicom in .NII format
// this works with gzip/gz/raw encoded NII files but XTK also supports other
// formats like MGH/MGZ, NRRD and DICOM
volume.file = 'http://x.babymri.org/?avf.nii';

r.add(volume);

r.render();
​
```

Lesson 10 shows something more advanced: http://lessons.goxtk.com/10/